# Why does this snippet of code yields "type mismatch; found: Unit required play.api.mvc.Result"?

Tags: scala

I am trying to add in a login/ authorisation wrapper around my application, but it is proving difficult.

Currently I am getting the following error

[image]

The code for Submission.scala is below

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

import anorm._

import views._

import models._

object Submission extends Controller with Secured {


  val contactForm:Form[Contact] = Form(

    mapping(
      "title" -> text,
      "firstname" -> text,
      "lastname" -> text,
      "gender" -> text,
      "dob" -> text,
      "mobile" -> text,
      "landline" -> text,
      "email" -> text,
      "housenumber1" -> text,
      "housename1" -> text,
      "address11" -> text,
      "address12" -> text,
      "address13" -> text,
      "address14" -> text,
      "address15" -> text,
      "postcode1" -> text,
      "country1" -> text  )
      (Contact.apply)(Contact.unapply)
    )



        def submit = TODO

  //def index = Action {
    //Ok(html.application());
  //}

  def index = IsAuthenticated { username => _ =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user =>
      Ok(
        html.index.apply()
      )
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)

  def form = Action {
   Ok(html.application(contactForm))
  }

  //def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    //val (fname, lname) = form.bindFromRequest.get
    //Ok("Hi %s %s".format(fname, lname))
  //}
}
}
```

I have tried to copy the relevant parts from the zentasks demo in the samples folder of Play but I seem to have missed something. I am new to both Play and Scala so the mistake could be a simple one.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a simple typo - you are missing a closing curly brace on the index function, then adding an extra closing curly brace after the form function (and commented out submit) - which means the last thing the index function does is define the form function as an inner function, which results in the index function returning `Unit`.

Comment: Couldn't see it for looking, thank you.